# Wireless won't connect at home but works elsewhere

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, router, connection

My laptop connects via a wire into the modem fine and it works without any problems but it wont connect to it wirelessly, when I've taken it out places it connects fine in wifi area's!

Also my son has his Wii connected wirelessly to it from his room upstairs without any problems, so I'm not sure where the problem lies, it hasn't worked since we got the modem it did on our old one and phoning Sky is just a waste of time they dont seem to know either and I just keep getting passed round departments repeating myself!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Interference?  Look for other WLAN routers nearby, and check their signal strength and channel number.  Change the channel number you use to be as far apart from other strong signals.

Other machines connected to the WLAN can also interfere.  My old i-Book won't connect to my household router if my wife has her laptop near the router, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Change the router to channel 11, which is the strongest and may avoid interference.

If you want help with how to do that, let me know the brand and model of your router.